# Place the last child next to the previous one - Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the below example, how can I place the *last child* (`CVV`) next to the *previous* one (`Expiry`), so they are on the same *row*:

```css
.form-col-1--cc {
  display: flex;
  flex: 30%;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-col-1--cc">
  <input matInput required class="example-full-width" name="number" card-number>
  <input required name="first-name" card-name matInput>
  <input matInput required name="expiry" card-expiry placeholder="Expiry">
  <input matInput required name="cvv" card-cvc placeholder="CVV">
</div>
```

Comment: For this 'two-dimensional' arrangement, have you considered using CSS Grid? [Demo one](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4dngstkm/), [demo two](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4dngstkm/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your inputs in another `div` like this:

```css
.form-col-1--cc {
  display: flex;
  flex: 30%;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-col-1--cc">              
  <input matInput required class="example-full-width" name="number" card-number>
  <input type="text" required name="first-name" card-name matInput>
  <div>
    <input matInput required type="text" name="expiry" card-expiry placeholder="Expiry">
    <input matInput required type="text" name="cvc" card-cvc placeholder="CVV">
  </div>
</div>
```